# jQuery validate, how to not validate required input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

For example I have `<input name="surname" id="surname" type="text">` 
Sometimes I make this input invisible and then I want, that this input will be not required.

My solution is when hidding input add value for example "some value" and when for is submited remove this value with PHP and not sore this defualt value to database.

But this is not good solution, this is more workaround, maybe is better solution to make `required` field not `required` and, but also must be solution to add back `required`.

I'm using jQuery validate plugin.

Comment: I am confused what you actually want!!

Comment: Put one condition before validating or adding to the database like the input field is visible or not.

Comment: Want make required field to not required

Comment: is a field is hidden, it will not be validate by default

Comment: I think we have 2 kinds of forcing `required`, automatic forcing `required` by using the `required` attribute, and programmatic forcing `required` by using code. So to make it not required, for the first, just remove the `required` attribute before submitting. For the second approach, just use code to control everything. So when it should not be required? It depends on your implemenation, looks like it's exactly when it should be invisible and I'm sure you know when it should be invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, apply a specific class to the fields you want to ignore.

```
$('inputfieldlist').addClass('ignoreClass');
```

Then,

```
$("#formName").validate({
   ignore: ".ignoreClass"
});
```

This will ignore all the elements with the class *ignoreClass*.

Read **[Jquery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)** for more details.

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP**:

> *"… maybe is better solution to make `required` field not required and, but also must be solution to add back `required`."*

Then this answer is exactly what you requested.  You will be able to "add" and "remove" rules whenever you wish using [the `.rules()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules).  (*Note:  This answer does not require that you alter any of the existing HTML markup or add/toggle any classes.*)

To dynamically add the `required` rule to `id="surname"`…

```
$('#surname').rules('add', {
    required: true
});
```

To dynamically remove the `required` rule from `id="surname"`…

```
$('#surname').rules('remove', 'required');
```

Although I'm not sure why you need to do any of this, as *by default* the invisible field will be ignored for validation.

Answer (score -1):

u can easy set. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7JCz3/) u can change required to true and see how that working

```
rules:{
    notrequired: {
        required: false
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use proper grammar and spelling within all answers.  Also, your answer makes no sense… you cannot "toggle" the `required` rule in this fashion.